# Excel Highlight Duplicates and Filter by color alternative

Tags: excel

My spreadsheet has about 800,000 rows with 30 columns. Customers are interested in duplicate values only in one column. They need the entire row back. For e.g.

```
MemberId|Name|Address|CircleScore
H111|John Doe|123 W Main|2.4
H222|Jane Doe|124 W Main|3.2
H333|Bob Doe|125 W Main|2.5
H444|Jake Doe|126 W Main|2.1
H555|Mike Doe|127 W Main|2.4
```

They want the entire rows where there are duplicates in CircleScore. So my filtered excel should only contain:

```
MemberId|Name|Address|CircleScore
H111|John Doe|123 W Main|2.4
H555|Mike Doe|127 W Main|2.4
```

I tried highlighting duplicate CircleScore and filtering, but the filtering part takes for ever.  I have waited for 15 minutes but still no luck. The duplicates could be around 150k.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create an `Is_Duplicated` indicator column and use that to filter the duplicated `CircleScores`:

[image: Excel Picture]

---

UPDATE (per comments):

Alternatively, you can `sort` the `CircleScore` column and make the formula a bit less taxing on your system (**NOTE `CircleScore` must be sorted beforehand**):

[image: Excel Alternative]

Comment: I like your method of using COUNTIFS(D:D,D2)>1; often when checking for duplicates I use something like ISERROR(MATCH(D2,$D$1:D1,0)). Yours I think is simpler, especially visually. Note however that this only works when *any* duplicate value requires special attention, not just the 2nd, 3rd, etc. values [ie: if you want the 1st iteration to be treated one way, and the 2nd etc. iterations treated another way, MATCH or a similar method may be better suited].

Comment: Thanks. Incredibly slow again. I had to kill it. The double click to drag the formula for all the cells is the culprit. 700,000 x 30 is too much to handle for excel eh. I have i7 3.4 GHz with 16 gigs of RAM.

Comment: @user3726933 have you considered PowerPivot or doing this in a database with SQL? If the interface still has to be Excel, I would potentially try to create the indicator column elsewhere and then load the data back into Excel. Alternatively, you could `sort` the `CircleScore` data first and modify the formula which should be less taxing (see my edit).

Answer (score 1):

> <sup>Please disregard this submission if you are a) getting paid by the hour and feel underpaid, b) planning on a nap while the routine processes, or c) both a) and b).</sup>

With any data set approaching 800K rows (with 30 columns) you are going to want to step into the variant array arena. With processing typically 5-7% of the time it takes to work with the worksheet values, it is very appropriate for large data blocks.

Anytime that the word 'duplicates' comes into play, I immediately start thinking about how a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object's unique index on its [Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/etzd1tzc.aspx) can benefit. In this solution I used a pair of dictionaries to identify the rows of data with a repeated *Circle Score* value.

Twenty-four million cells of data is a lot to store and transfer. Bulk methods beat individual methods every time and the bulkiest method of peeling off the data would be to stuff all 800K rows × 30 columns into a variant array. All processing becomes in-memory and the results are returned to a report worksheet *en masse*.

**[isolateDuplicateCircleScores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137329/excel-highlight-duplicates-and-filter-by-color-alternative/35151456#35151456) code**

```
Sub isolateDuplicateCircleScores()
    Dim d As Long, v As Long, csc As Long, stmp As String
    Dim ky As Variant, itm As Variant, vVALs As Variant, dCSs As Object, dDUPs As Object
    Dim w As Long, vWSs As Variant
    'early binding
    'dim dCSs As new scripting.dictionary, dDUPs As new scripting.dictionary

    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    'late binding - not necessary with Early Binding (see footnote ¹)
    Set dCSs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dDUPs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'set to the defaults (not necessary)
    dCSs.comparemode = vbBinaryCompare
    dDUPs.comparemode = vbBinaryCompare

    'for testing on multiple row number scenarios
    'vWSs = Array("CircleScores_8K", "CircleScores_80K", "CircleScores_800K")
    'for runtime
    vWSs = Array("CircleScores")  '<~~ your source worksheet here

    For w = LBound(vWSs) To UBound(vWSs)
        'ThisWorkbook.Save
        Debug.Print vWSs(w)
        Debug.Print Timer
        With Worksheets(vWSs(w))

            On Error Resume Next
            Worksheets(vWSs(w) & "_dupes").Delete
            On Error GoTo 0

            ReDim vVALs(0)
            dCSs.RemoveAll
            dDUPs.RemoveAll

            'prep a new worksheet to receive the duplicates
            .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Resize(2).Copy
            With Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(.Index))
                .Name = vWSs(w) & "_dupes"
                With .Cells(1, 1)
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone
                    .Value = .Value2
                    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.ClearContents
                End With
            End With
            'finish prep with freeze row 1 and zoom to 80%
            With Application.Windows(1)
                .SplitColumn = 0
                .SplitRow = 1
                .FreezePanes = True
                .Zoom = 80
            End With

            'grab all of the data into a variant array
            ReDim vVALs(0)
            csc = Application.Match("CircleScore", .Rows(1), 0) 'CircleScore column number needed later
            vVALs = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), _
                           .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, csc).End(xlUp).Row, _
                                  .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Value2
            'Debug.Print LBound(vVALs, 1) & ":" & UBound(vVALs, 1)  '1:~800K
            'Debug.Print LBound(vVALs, 2) & ":" & UBound(vVALs, 2)  '1:~30
        End With    'done with the original worksheet

        'populate the dDUPs dictionary using the key index in dCSs
        For v = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
            If dCSs.exists(vVALs(v, csc)) Then
                stmp = vVALs(v, 1)
                For d = LBound(vVALs, 2) + 1 To UBound(vVALs, 2)
                    stmp = Join(Array(stmp, vVALs(v, d)), ChrW(8203))
                Next d
                dDUPs.Add Key:=v, Item:=stmp
                If Not dDUPs.exists(dCSs.Item(vVALs(v, csc))) Then
                    stmp = vVALs(dCSs.Item(vVALs(v, csc)), 1)
                    For d = LBound(vVALs, 2) + 1 To UBound(vVALs, 2)
                        stmp = Join(Array(stmp, vVALs(dCSs.Item(vVALs(v, csc)), d)), ChrW(8203))
                    Next d
                    dDUPs.Add Key:=dCSs.Item(vVALs(v, csc)), Item:=stmp
                End If
            Else
                dCSs.Item(vVALs(v, csc)) = v
            End If
        Next v

        'split the dDUPs dictionary items back into a variant array
        d = 1
        ReDim vVALs(1 To dDUPs.Count, 1 To UBound(vVALs, 2))
        For Each ky In dDUPs.keys
            itm = Split(dDUPs.Item(ky), ChrW(8203))
            For v = LBound(itm) To UBound(itm)
                vVALs(d, v + 1) = itm(v)
            Next v
            d = d + 1
        Next ky

        'put the values into the duplicates worksheet
        With Worksheets(vWSs(w) & "_dupes")
            .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(vVALs, 1), UBound(vVALs, 2)) = vVALs
            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    .Rows(1).Copy
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone
                End With
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(csc), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Key2:=.Columns(1), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            End With
        End With

        Debug.Print Timer
    Next w

    dCSs.RemoveAll: Set dCSs = Nothing
    dDUPs.RemoveAll: Set dDUPs = Nothing

    appTGGL
End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .AutoRecover.Enabled = bTGGL   'no interruptions with an auto-save
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

**[Sample Data and Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB55v.png)**

[image: duplicateIdentification_800K]
        <sup>800K rows × 30 columns of random sample data</sup>

[image: duplicateIdentification_800K_results]
        <sup>~123K rows × 30 columns of duplicate rows (sorted and formatted in about a minute-and-a-half)</sup>

**[Timed Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JYH6.png)**

tbh, I never got the 32-bit version of Excel on the older laptop to run the 800K pass run more than once without restarting Excel. Once restarted the results were consistent with what is shown. The 64-bit Excel ran repeatedly without a hiccup.

[image: duplicateIdentification_results]

<sup>**Large Worksheet Addendum**</sup>

<sup>When dealing with worksheets containing large data blocks there are a few general improvements that can limit your wait times. You're using Excel as a medium sized database tool so treat the data worksheet as the raw data that it should be.</sup>

- <sup>If you are not working with a 64-bit version of Excel then you are wasting time with everything you do. See [What version of Office am I using?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-version-of-Office-am-I-using-932788b8-a3ce-44bf-bb09-e334518b8b19) and [Choose the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-Office-2DEE7807-8F95-4D0C-B5FE-6C6F49B8D261).</sup>
- <sup>Save as an Excel Binary Workbook (e.g. .XLSB). The file size is typically 25-35% of the original. Load times are improved and some calculation is quicker (sorry, do not have empirical timed data on the latter). Some operations that crash an .XLSX or .XLSM work fine with an .XLSB.</sup>
- <sup>Disable Auto-Save/Auto-Recover in the options for the workbook. ([alt]+F, T, S, [alt]+D, [OK]). There are few things more irritating than waiting for an auto-save to complete when you are trying to do something. Get used to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> when **YOU** want to save.</sup>
- <sup>Avoid volatile functions¹ at all costs; particularly in formulas that are used in the full scope of the data. A single `TODAY()` in a COUNTIF formula filled down for the extent of the rows will have you sitting on your thumb more often than not.</sup>
- <sup>Speaking of formulas, revert all formulas to their result values whenever possible.</sup>
- <sup>Merged cells, conditional formatting, data validation and making cells look pretty with formatting and styles slows you down. Minimize the use of anything that takes away from raw data. It isn't like anyone is actually going to look through 800K rows of data.</sup>
- <sup>After removing data use Home ► Editing ► Clear ► Clear All on the vacant cells. Tapping the <kbd>Del</kbd> only clears the contents and may not reset the 
  [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx); Clear All will facilitate resetting the .Used Range on the next save.</sup>
- <sup>If you have hooped your computer with one or more Excel [Not Responding] scenarios, reboot your machine. Excel never fully recovers from these and simply restarting Excel to start over is slower and more likely to enter the same Not Responding condition later.</sup>

---

¹ <sub>If you can convert the late binding of the Scripting.Dictionary to early binding, you must add **[Microsoft Scripting Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat.aspx)** to the VBE's Tools ► References.</sub>

² <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: The random sample data workbook (XLSB) is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/duplicateIndentificationReport.xlsb) for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot 1]

Try this Vba-code (and learn a little bit Dutch)

```
Sub DuplicatesInColumn()
'maakt een lijst met de aangetroffen dubbelingen
Dim LaatsteRij As Long
Dim MatchNr As Long
Dim iRij, iKolom, iTeller, Teller As Long, ControlKolom As Long
iRij = 1

iKolom = 5                   'number of columns in the sheet, Chance if not correct
ControlKolom = 4             'column number where to find the doubles, Chance if not correct

LaatsteRij = Cells(65000, iKolom).End(xlUp).Row: iTeller = iKolom

Sheet1.Activate
For iRij = 1 To LaatsteRij
    If Cells(iRij, ControlKolom) <> "" Then
        MatchNr = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iRij, ControlKolom), Range(Cells(1, ControlKolom), Cells(LaatsteRij, ControlKolom)), 0)
    If iRij <> MatchNr Then
    iTeller = iKolom
    For Teller = 1 To iTeller
      Cells(iRij, iKolom + Teller).Offset(0, 2).Value = Range(Cells(iRij, Teller), Cells(iRij, Teller)).Value
    Next Teller
    End If: End If
Next
End Sub
```