# Removing duplicates, keeping last entry -- optimization

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro that will go through a spreadsheet and remove duplicate entries (rows) based on two criteria that are provided separately in two columns (columns Q and D).

Here is what I have. I tested it out on a small dataset and it's *slow*.

```
Sub RemoveDupesKeepLast()
dim i As Integer
dim criteria1, criteria2 As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

'start at bottom of sheet, go up
For i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count to 2 Step -1

    'if there is no entry, go to next row
    If Cells(i, "Q").Value = "" Then
        GoTo gogo:
    End If

    'set criteria that we will filter for
    criteria1 = Cells(i, "D").Value
    criteria2 = Cells(i, "Q").Value

    'filter for criteria2, then criteria1 to get duplicates
    ActiveSheet.Range("A":"CI").AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:=criteria2, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("A":"CI").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=criteria1, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    'if there are duplicates, keep deleting rows until only bottom-most entry is left behind
    Do While Range("Q2", Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1,17).EntireRow.Delete
    Loop

    'reset autofilter
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        Cells.AutoFilter
    End If

gogo:
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Is there a different way I can approach this problem to speed things up? As it is right now, I'm basically checking each row until I get to the top. The sheets are actually anywhere from 30,000 rows to the max. Seems to me that there should be a faster, cleaner way of achieving what I'm trying to do but I can't seem to think of one.

Comment: what you want to do now? concaetenate Q & D value and search the duplicates in A to C columns?

Comment: What are the rules defining a duplicate?

Comment: @Karthick I'm not concatenating any values. For every row in my sheet, I'm looking at the values in the Q and D columns to filter through the entire sheet for duplicates. Duplicates will have the same Q and D values. Therefore if I filter for Q and D, if there is more than one row present then there are duplicates. Then I delete the topmost rows and leave the bottommost. I'm only looking to get rid of the duplicates and keep the last entry -- nothing else.

Comment: @FlorentB. Duplicates will have the same values in columns Q and D.

Comment: so you applying the same value on Q and D right?

Comment: I'm not surprised that is slow. A much faster way will be to put a formula in the spreadsheet that returns true for duplicates other than the last occurance, then delete all "True" rows in one go. You could also use a scripting dictionary to accomplish your goal,  which would be lightning fast. If I get time I'll punch up some code

Comment: If your data set(s) scope is *' anywhere from 30,000 rows to the max.'* then why is `i` dimmed as an integer?

Comment: @Jeeped Good point...I made this for a test case that only had 1000 rows so I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100,00 rows × 87 columns in 40.3 seconds.

If your data set(s) start at 30K rows and only get bigger you should be looking to in-memory processing whenever possible¹. I've adapted the methods used in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137329/excel-highlight-duplicates-and-filter-by-color-alternative/35151456#35151456) to more closely follow your requirements.

The following bulk loads all values into a variant array and builds a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object from the results. The 'overwrite' method of adding keys to the dictionary is used so that only the last one is kept.

When the collation has been performed, the values are returned to a re-dimensioned variant array and restored to the worksheet *en masse*.

**[Module1 (Code)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Removing%20duplicates%2C%20keeping%20last%20entry%20%E2%80%94%20optimization.xlsb)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub removeDupesKeepLast()
    Dim d As Long, dDQs As Object, ky As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, vVALs As Variant, vTMP As Variant

    'appTGGL bTGGL:=False   'uncomment this when you have finished debugging

    Set dDQs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dDQs.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    'step 1 - bulk load the values
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   'you should know what worksheet you are on
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion 'block of data radiating out from A1
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0) 'step off the header row
                vVALs = .Value  'use .Value2 if you do not have dates in unformatted cells
            End With
        End With
    End With

    'step 2 - build the dictionary
    ReDim vTMP(UBound(vVALs, 2) - 1)
    For r = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
        For c = LBound(vVALs, 2) To UBound(vVALs, 2)
            vTMP(c - 1) = vVALs(r, c)
        Next c
        dDQs.Item(vVALs(r, 4) & ChrW(8203) & vVALs(r, 17)) = vTMP
    Next r

    'step 3 - put the de-duplicated values back into the array
    r = 0
    ReDim vVALs(1 To dDQs.Count, LBound(vVALs, 2) To UBound(vVALs, 2))
    For Each ky In dDQs
        r = r + 1
        vTMP = dDQs.Item(ky)
        For c = LBound(vTMP) To UBound(vTMP)
            vVALs(r, c + 1) = vTMP(c)
        Next c
    Next ky

    'step 4 - clear the destination; put the de-duplicated values back into the worksheet and reset .UsedRange
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   'you should know what worksheet you are on
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion 'block of data radiating out from A1
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0) 'step off the header row
                .ClearContents  'retain formatting if it is there
                .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vVALs, 1), UBound(vVALs, 2)) = vVALs
            End With
        End With
        .UsedRange   'assert the UsedRange property (refreshes it)
    End With

    dDQs.RemoveAll: Set dDQs = Nothing

    appTGGL
End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .AutoRecover.Enabled = bTGGL   'no interruptions with an auto-save
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

My sample workbook took 100K rows × 87 column with ~24% duplicates and processed all duplicates (keeping the last entries) in ~40 seconds. The above writes back to Sheet1; my tests were run writing back to Sheet2 in order to retain the original data. If you choose to write back to a different worksheet, make sure that there are some values starting at A1 in order that the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) can be properly identified. The test machine was an older laptop running 32-bit Excel 2010; your own results will likely vary.

---

¹ <sub>See [Highlight Duplicates and Filter by color alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137329/excel-highlight-duplicates-and-filter-by-color-alternative/35151456#35151456) for tip[s on dealing with large data sets in Excel.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. I made the modifications and it all looks to work perfectly for my cases.

Answer (score 2):

This procedure deletes all the duplicated rows identified by column D and Q.
Among duplicates, it will keep the row the closest to the bottom of the sheet.
Basically, an indexed column is created on the right to sort and move all the duplicated rows at the bottom so they can be deleted in a single call.
Note that it doesn't alter the cells formula or format if there is any.

```
Sub DeleteDuplicatedRows()
  Dim rgTable As Range, rgIndex As Range, dataColD(), dataColQ()

  Set rgTable = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

  ' load each column representing the identifier in an array
  dataColD = rgTable.Columns("D").value  ' load values from column D
  dataColQ = rgTable.Columns("Q").value  ' load values from column Q

  ' get each unique row number with a dictionary
  Dim dict As New VBA.collection, indexes(), r&, rr
  On Error Resume Next
  For r = UBound(dataColD) To 1 Step -1
    dict.Add r, dataColD(r, 1) & vbNullChar & dataColQ(r, 1)
  Next
  On Error GoTo 0

  ' index all the unique rows in an array
  ReDim indexes(1 To UBound(dataColD), 1 To 1)
  For Each rr In dict: indexes(rr, 1) = rr: Next

  ' insert the indexes in the last column on the right
  Set rgIndex = rgTable.Columns(rgTable.Columns.count + 1)
  rgIndex.value = indexes

  ' sort the rows on the indexes, duplicates will move at the end
  Union(rgTable, rgIndex).Sort key1:=rgIndex, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes

  ' delete the index column on the right and the empty rows at the bottom
  rgIndex.EntireColumn.Delete
  rgTable.Resize(UBound(dataColD) - dict.count + 1).offset(dict.count).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry Florent, maybe I should've chose my wording a little more carefully. Duplicate *rows* will have the same values in columns "D" and "Q". So I'm looking for duplicate rows, not rows where D = Q

Comment: I should have guessed. I've updated my answer to match your requirements. It is faster than @Jeeped solution and it doesn't alter the content of the cell or the format.

Comment: Thanks Florent. Looks to work perfectly and very quickly as well :)

Comment: @Florent B.  I have used your answer in my code but when the lines  ' delete the index column on the right and the empty rows at the bottom
  rgIndex.EntireColumn.Delete
  rgTable.Resize(UBound(dataColD) - dict.count + 1).offset(dict.count).EntireRow.Delete

execute it deletes everything on the excel worksheet.